# is there a way to make multiple color along a path in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

I have a curved path, I tried to duplicate it 3 times And play with the strokes and the offset, but the line crosses itself when there's a curve.

Is there A better way to make a multiple color along a path? Thanks for the help

[image]